# How to generate an RSASSA-PSS signature with MGF1-SHA256?

Tags: rsa, signature, implementation, rsa-pss

As part of rooting a device, I need to generate a 256-byte RSASSA-PSS signature using SHA256 as the hash and MGF1-SHA256 as the mask function, for an [update file](http://net87.net46.net/data.img) I created.  I can choose any 32-byte key; moreover, I am provided with a default key, namely

```
49db67e9a6f198be22b03e84dedd69b834ba67d42e017d2f1ef08f0203010001
```

However, I have no clue what those terms mean (e.g. mask function???).  The rooting guide refers to a [specification sheet](ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-1/pkcs-1v2-1.pdf) online, that details how these encryption algorithms work.  Would I have to follow all the steps in that file one by one, or has this algorithm already been programmed somewhere, in a way that I can provide the file and the key, and it can give me the 256-byte hash?

I apologize in advance if this is not the type of questions that are typically asked on the crypto site; but [**I asked on the meta**](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747), and did not get a response about where I can ask this; and, this is the last step of a day-long root, so I really wish to get this done.

Comment: RSASSA-PSS  is indeed implemented quite often and finding an implementation shouldn't be all too hard. I don't know whether it is already implemented as "give me the file and the key and I give you the signature", but "give me something to sign (in memory) and the key and I give you the signature" certainly is implemented.

Comment: It seems to me that you've only got part of the public key. With just (part of) the public key you won't be able to create a signature. A 256 byte PSS signature indicates a 2048 bit private key. Your key ends however with `0203010001`, which is the ASN.1 encoding of the fourth Fermat prime, which is often used as *public* exponent. The part before that is likely the last part of the modulus (also public).